# Getting a uniform OFFSET().TOP from transformed element

Tags: javascript, css, transform, offset

I'm retrieving text from ajax which feeds a tile whose content changes every 5 seconds. The tile's height is variable so I need to get the offset between the text and another element to set the correct height for the text. (let's say it's like a tile that feeds from Facebook statuses and I have to make sure it doesn't come on top of an absolute-positioned element at the bottom.

Here, the codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kFsif (test in webkit, open the console)

What happens is that, as the element is being transformed, sometimes I get a different offset (should always be the same), ranging (in this example) from 62.1875 to even 47.24595642089844. 5 pixels are a lot in my case.

My question is: Is there a way to obtain the offset().top (or it could also be the position().top) of an element that is being transformed so that it gives me always a consistent result?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is an example of how the final markup looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/n3KvJ/

Imagine what I'm trying to do is to set `.medium` height so that it doesn't touch `.bottom`. Problem is: `.tile` height is variable and the position I'm getting changes during a transform.

Comment: I feel like overflow and a padding value on the bottom would be your answer but let me look; EDIT: For which element are you trying to change?

Comment: then why not just standardize .tile height and add an overflow?

Comment: Because `.tile`'s height is variable. I can't set it to a determined value.

Comment: I suppose I'm just not understanding why `.tile`'s height is variable. You could have it set to ensure that it is a certain height, and if there is an overflow that it will scroll down slowly to view it, but I suppose that is beside the point. I'm not 100% with transitions in CSS, so give me a minute to fiddle around with it when I get done with some work.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, making sure it's a certain height would be very easy, but it is not possible, it has to be variable :S